# Change HTTP Status Code in Genexus Procedure Rest

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, genexus

Does anyone know how to change response HTTP Status Code in a procedure type REST in Genexus?

I generated an api rest and it is always responding Http code 200, and I need to change the response to 400 when there is an error.

Answer (score 4):

API object is available in Genexus 17 for Net and Net Core generators, and GeneXus 17 Upgrade 2 for Java generator. API Object allows you to customize the HTTP Status  Code through a predefined variable called &RestCode. [Here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?46151,Category%3AAPI%20object) the wiki for the API Object.
If you're using an older version, there is a way to solve the problem writting external code directly in the PRC as explained [here](https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=42949;;).

Depending wich generator are you using the external code is something like this:

.Net generator:

```
CSHARP [!&httresponse!].Response.StatusCode = 406;
```

Java generator:

```
&statusCode = 200
java context.getHttpContext().getResponse().setStatus([!&statusCode!]);
```

Ok, that code doesn't seems to work in GeneXus Evolution 3 when the PRC is exposed as REST. Doing a little research in the Java Generator, you can modify the StatusCode this way:

[image]

And the rules are:

[image]

It's a very simple PRC exposed as REST who takes a number as input and generates a String with that number.
Don't know exactly how to do that in Net generator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'am using GX Ev3. I don't understand where to put that code, because I'm just generating a procedure with property Rest in True. Could you please explain me where I can use that code

Comment: Ok, edited my reply adding further information about your specific case, I've found a solution for Java generator but my lack of knowledge in C# prevents doing the same in such generator.

Comment: Leandro very clear your explanation, I tried and it is working. Thank you so much!